# Crack in joint between molding and ceiling

Tags: repair, plaster, trim, crack

I have a very old house with plaster walls. After getting a new roof, a large crack opened up between the molding and the ceiling where the wall is pulling away, but only along the one outside wall. The rest of the walls are fine. The molding used to be a picture rail but a previous owner filled in the 1/2" gap between the molding and the ceiling; that is where it's cracked and the old plaster is falling out. The crack going down the side I can fix, but I'm not sure how to deal with the missing molding in the corner there. [image] I really don't want to remove and replace all the molding. Any suggestions on fixing?

Answer (score 3):

> **I really don't want to remove and replace all the molding. Any suggestions on fixing?**

If the crack has stopped growing and the wall is stable, you could just remove any loose plaster/filler, apply new filler and repaint. You'd need a "deep crack" filler.

If the crack is still growing and is as large as it looks, you have a more urgent and more important problem needing professional help.

Comment: Thank you! The crack had stopped growing. I didn't see this in time and removed the molding from just that wall, which was probably a mistake! I will try to use the deep crack fill, and then a metal corner bead over that to reconstruct the corner before putting the molding back on. I may end up back on this site if it doesn't work!